# Sum All the Post Meta of Published posts of Current Logged in user

Tags: php, plugin-development, custom-field

I found the below code to count post views in WordPress. I needed 2 things from this, which I am not able to do yet.

1. Author stats: How to show the current logged in user, the total views of all the published posts via shortcode. How can I handle this? I found an answer on WPSE for showing the total views but it doesn't add shortcode and gets views of all posts, I want views of all the published posts
2. For representing the data, how to show the views of each and every author in a html table, not just current author, all the authors, just the author name and  total post views. This can be useful for multi author sites and can be used to track performance of all the authors.

```
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.

function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

I tried to do a array of all the post ids of current user but I failed. I also tried to add a Author id, portion in this post meta to make easy. But none seemed to work.

Here's the current code implementation

```
 function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'Creation_Views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    } 
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'Creation_Views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}


function get_meta_value_by_meta_key($key, $values, $sum){
    global $wpdb;

    $metaValues = array();
    $key= 'Creation_views';
    $query = "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '$key'";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    var_dump($results);
    if(!empty($results) && !is_null($results)){
        foreach($results as $result){
            foreach($result as $value){
                $metaValues[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    //get_results returns null on failure
    if(is_null($results) && WP_DEBUG == true){
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $wpdb->print_error();
    }
    return $metaValues;
$values = get_meta_value_by_meta_key('Creation_views');
$sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $values));
}
add_shortcode('Stats','get_meta_value_by_meta_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom query, to get data from `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` depending on the `meta_key` and store the `meta_value`s inside an array, then sum them.

So we can build a function like this:

```
/**
* Query meta values by meta key.
* 
* @return int Returns sum of meta values
*/

function get_meta_value_by_meta_key(){
    global $wpdb;

    $metaValues = array();

    $query = "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Creation_Views'";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    if(!empty($results) && !is_null($results)){
        foreach($results as $result){
            foreach($result as $value){
                $metaValues[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    //get_results returns null on failure
    if(is_null($results) && WP_DEBUG == true){
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $wpdb->print_error();
    }
    $sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $metaValues));
    return $sum;

   }
 add_shortcode('Stats', get_meta_value_by_meta_key());
```

Comment: Well that seems the right idea, i will surely test and get back to you in some time...

Comment: seems like it doesn't work. i added a shortcode, and then added `function get_meta_value_by_meta_key($key, $values, $sum)` and then put `$sum and $ values` at end of function. on frontend the shortcode returns the word 'array' rather than having the data or sum...

Comment: i assume that the problem is    $metaValues = array(); because the array has not been given the data

Comment: have you tried the code directly without the shortcode

Comment: well i tried to run it in after content of posts and it didn't run there too. so i have tried at shortcode as well as a filter..

Comment: Would you please `var_dump` the variable `$results`. and tell me what happens

Comment: no success... just to inform you that i have put the var dump at the end of function. i am not a very experienced php coder, and i consider you the expert, shall i share you the exact code that i am running, because it feels that we are really close to our goal

Comment: if you wish i can email you my code, or i can add my exact code including your implementation in the question itself

Comment: not at the end of the function, just after the variable definition

Comment: if you can't follow, you can edit the question about what you are exactly doing to help others when they visit here later

Comment: thanks for it, i updated the code in question, and as of now it's still not working... how about doing a `$meta_values= array($query)`

Comment: you can check the current code implementation above...

Comment: Now I know what is wrong, I will write the full code within my answer, just i can't right now, I will post it today

Comment: Thanks You sir, i shall wait, code is poetry, and i love how coders like you accomplish the unknown so easily. Thanks for your support.....

Comment: I have edited the answer, would you please check it.

Comment: it starts showing a numeric value so i assume that it shows correct sum of meta values, i will verify it by manually adding them and matching but till then thank you. It's been a great help

Comment: Hey there, i think it's too late, but their is another piece of the puzzle that i need. Your code does a wpdb query for all the posts, for postmeta. Can you please help me select the posts for current logged in user

Comment: How can we add the postmeta for all the posts of the current logged-in user. Your code sums it for each and every post, can we sum it for current logged in user?

Comment: Dude any help in this matter?